# Twitter API 1.0 to 1.1 with dotnet framework 2.0

Tags: vb.net

I am using Titterizer for twitter interaction using vb.net website, as twitter has updated its API 1.0 to 1.1 twitterizer is now not working it requiring latest framwork of dot net but my application is on 2.0 i can not change its framwork right now  ,i got some suggestion to use TweetSharp but I dont know hoe to use it in the existence of twitterizer..
I am getting this error

{"errors":[{"message":"The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.","code":64}]}

I am very careful as i am working on production environment. 
please assist..

Thanks- SFaiq

Comment: You need to be a lot more clear on your problem. For example, what error message are you having?

Comment: I am getting this error


{"errors":[{"message":"The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.","code":64}]}

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest version of the Twitterizer library; older versions of the library were hard coded for the 1.0 Twitter API. This has been corrected in later versions.

Comment: I have used the updated dll files of twitterizer but framework is not accepting any more..

Comment: any one ??
Now I am fed up with this issue for last week!!

Comment: You'll have to be clearer.  What do you mean when you say "framework is not accepting any more"?

Comment: Means I am working on dotnet frameWork 2.0 and twitterizerudated dll is for latest framework therefore my old framework is not getting accept

Comment: Check to see if your existing application will work under Framework 4.0 (most application written for 2.0 will work under 4.0 with no modifications).  If that is not an option, then you'll need to either find a different library or write some sort of service/abstraction layer to broker requests between your application and the Twitterizer library.